# How can I redirect http://mywebsite/blog developed in asp.net to http://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have seen multiple questions related to this post. Unfortunately I am unable to find any answer. Actually my question is that, How can I redirect //webname/blog developed in asp.net and hosted on IIS 7.5 to webname.azurewebsites.net/ which is a wordpress blog. I tried that using Intelligencia.UrlRewriter as bellow but it doesn't work.

```
<rewrite url="/blog/" to="http://webname.azurewebsites.net/" StatusCode="301"/>
<if url="/blog$">
<rewrite to="http://webname.azurewebsites.net/" processing="stop" />
</if>
```

Could you kindly help to do this.